# include file and it's content

Tags: lua, include-path

How do I import or include a file into Lua code. I wanted to fetch the file's content which I am including into function.

What are the functions into Lua which will loads when lua file will get loaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the Lua [modules documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.3).

Comment: which version of lua are you using?

Comment: @Mike Corcoran : Lua Version 5.1

Answer (score 2):

You normally use either [`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-require) or [`dofile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-dofile), depending of your situation. It is also possible to call the lower level functions [`loadfile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-loadfile) or [`load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load) if you need more flexibility.

- [`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-require) is used to load library modules. The argument is the name of the module, and Lua then searches for the file in the `package.path` path. It also maintains a cache of loaded modules, so that the second time you call `require` for the same name it will only return the cached value.
- [`dofile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-dofile) is simpler. It just take the file path as argument. It loads and executes the code every time it is called.

Comment: yes, I am dofile method itself, for including the file, so that I could fetch it's content through if dofile method will work. But my dofile method or that syntax is not compiling/executing properly. As this Lua code I am integrating into the XML code and in between xml code I am integrating the Lua code, so may be that will be the reason hence it's not executing the dofile code. So what will be the another ways to get it done in a simple manner.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is your calling syntax and what is the error message (if any) ? It is possible that `dofile` is not included in your environment. If not, please check for existence of `require`, `load` and `loadfile`.

Comment: I am working in xml file, where some of the code is been developed into Lyua. lua code is almost written into proper syntax like we do into Php <?php .. ?> this tag. I am occuring error such as "cannot open filename. S.lua: No such file or directory (funcitonname)"o how would I make it work out to resolve that issue.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like `dofile` is present and probably working. Now, the file path is probably incorrect. What is possible is that you are providing a relative file path and the current working directory of your application is not what you expected. Try to provide a full absolute file path.

Comment: Ok now, as per your post, I have tried to put absolute and dynamic path as well into dofile and require method as well still it is showing same message but in diff. manner. My files which I am including is in same directory.

Comment: can anyone please suggest any other method to make it work out.